# How do I guarantee uniqueness of a table value only within a subset of the table rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of projects belonging to various users:

**project_id, owner_user_id, project_name**

I do not need the project_names to be globally unique to the table, so making project_name UNIQUE does not help.  I would just like to prevent the user from creating duplicate project_names on INSERT or UPDATE.

Upon INSERT/UPDATE, I simply want to check if there is already a project_name belonging to a specific owner_user_id, and if it already exists, the INSERT/UPDATE should fail.

I could use a SELECT to first check for existence of the project_name within the user's projects, and then only do an INSERT/UPDATE if the select returns no results.  But this is multi-threaded and another thread could INSERT the same project_name immediately after I perform the SELECT but before the INSERT/UPDATE.  Putting this all into a transaction feels like overkill.  Is there a single query that can perform this instead?

Comment: is their one to may relation between owner_user_id and project_name? i mean one user could have different project_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [UNIQUE constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on the two columns as a pair:

```
alter table your_table add unique (owner_user_id, project_name)
```

That will ensure that `project_name` values are unique per-user. You'll want to have a look at your [collation set up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-sensitivity.html) to make sure your `project_name` values are compared without regard to case. Or you could standardize the project names to title case before hitting the database.

Don't try to maintain data integrity by hand unless you have to, let the database take care of  your constraints whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

This does need to be in a transaction. You need to retrieve some information ("which names are already in use?") and then act on it ("if my name is not in use, then use it"). This must be done atomically.

As you have correctly surmised, there is a race condition if the insert does not happen atomically after the check.

This is what transactions are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique constraint on both fields

```
 CONSTRAINT C_UNICITY UNIQUE (owner_user_id, project_name)
```

Each time you try to insert or update a record which present duplicate, you'll get a sql error

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from Project where owner_user_id='1';");         
if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
    $result = mysql_query("insert into Project (projectname) values ('pojectname');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on database referential integrity violations to throw errors for you to trap is not generally a preferred form of UI validation - you generally want something at a higher abstraction level anyway. But there's nothing particularly "overkill" about using transactions  and UNIQUE constraints liberally to protect your data as much as your users.

Comment: Could you elaborate why using database integrity violations is not a preferred form of UI validation?  I found "mu is too short"s answer rather elegant.  Are you saying this kind of validation should not be "hidden" within the database constraints, but more visible in business logic code, or is there some other reason?  Regarding the "overkill" of transactions: This application otherwise will not need them, so I'm trying to retain the speed advantage of MyIASM over InnoDB.

Comment: For starters the error messages from the database aren't usually designed for end users. And ordinarily there's more to what constitutes an acceptable project name than any combination of byte-strings the table doesn't already have a key for. Are you really on the verge of overtaxing innodb?